# How to access popup form with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Have been trying for a while to figure out how to handle popup form using selenium python.

Have a element "add" after clicking it which opens a new popup where I have to enter value. Not able to find the element to insert the value.
There is no iframe used.

HTML code for the popup looks like:

```
<div id="form-1322" class="xyz" >
 <div id="form-1322-body" class="xyz1" >
  <span id="outerCt" role="presentation"">
   <div id="innerCt"role="presentation"">
    <table id="ext-comp-1317" class="xyz2" >
     <tbody>
      <td id="body1" class="xyz4">
       <input id="body2" class="xyz5" name="abc">
```

Need to insert a value in -> name="abc" but Unable to locate element.

code used:

```
Name=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="body2"][@class="xyz5"][@name="abc"]')
Name.send_keys("login")
```

Comment: I don't think  this is your real  problem. But you have one x to much in your xpath @class="xxyz5'. Anyway selecting by id should be enough. Perhaps you need do add a delay to wait that the popup is added before try to get the input element.

Comment: one extra 'x' was a typing mistake here. After adding delay too not able to locate the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely that selenium is "too fast" and is looking for the element before it appears on the page. try using a WebDriverWait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="body2"][@class="xxyz5"][@name="abc"]')
element.send_keys('login")
```

Comment: getting.....raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)....after using the this code.